# Get all (multiple) values of a data.frame falling into every raster cell

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

I have spatial data with lat/long (x/y) and want to put a raster on it. I want to get all values inside every raster cell where the respective points fit into. The points are not equally distributed so one raster cell does not contain the same amount of points as the neighbouring raster cell. I know that there is the function rasterize that uses the mean to average all values inside that cell into one new value but I dont want to interpolate the mean inside the cell, I want to extract all values (here `values` of points inside that cell).

How can I do this in an effective way?

consider I have:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
```

my data:

```
x <- runif(n) * 360 - 180
y <- runif(n) * 180 - 90
n <- 1000
values=runif(n)
xy <- cbind(x,y)
```

my raster

```
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
```

Now I dont want to average all values like using rasterize, but extract all `values` (e.g into a list) that fall into that cell.

Many thanks for ideas and help! Is there any function for this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to have values in the raster to be sampled. In your example you are just trying to sample an empty raster. ( I mistook this for your sample size in the originals edit; issue is with your example, not the question)

To answer your question...
extract() is the function you are looking for:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
n <- 1000
x <- runif(n) * 360 - 180
y <- runif(n) * 180 - 90
values=runif(n)
r[]<-values

xy <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data=data.frame(cbind(x,y)),coords=cbind(x,y))


r0 <- extract(r, xy)

plot(r0)
```

Comment: thanks! but this does not tackle my problem. I reduced the  ratser size to make my problem more precise. I have multiple points that fit into the raster cell so there is not one unique value for every raster cell. the vector values is larger than the raster because multiple values fall into one cell. this makes it problematic to use extract as here the number of cells and values must be the same? I could use rasterize to take the mean which gives me the averaged value of the vector values for every cell but I want to extract every value inside that cell.

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood your question. Would it be accurate to state that you want to find the mean of some points for a given raster cell?

Comment: thanks first for your help! No, I want to extract all values in the raster cell not the mean, the mean I could extract using rasterize (FUN = mean) but as the amount of possible matches of values falling into one raster cell is not constant (as based on runif) there are multiple values matching into a raster cell. my question is how I could extract all of them instead of the mean .But I think the function cellFromXY() is the answer.

Comment: So reading your question, it sounds like you want your result to be a list, something in the form of [PointID, X location, Y location, Point Value, Raster Value at Point location].  So here, extract is pulling the value of the raster at each location of the SPDF. So I guess my question becomes how important is the identity of the raster cell that a point is pulling from. So not to be critical, but I do think extract is doing what you want (as you've described here). I *think* what you may be looking for, is to rather than summarize the raster by the SPDF, summarize the SPDF by the raster?

Comment: but there is no raster value to extract from, I have an empty raster and a list with X and Y locations. Now for every point I want to find the raster cell where the point fits into. More than 1 of these points in the list could fit into a raster cell, so for every raster cell the result is different in length. with cellfromXY() I get the rastercell id for every point so this is more what I want. But thanks anyways and tell me if I missunderstood extract().

Comment: But to be clear, the list will **always** be as long as the number of points. I think an important thing to understand that when you are defined the raster, you are deciding which cells a thing lands in. So in fact, you already have that information in the X and Y coordinate of your SPDF. Its important to understand that generally, rasters aren't defined in terms of individual cell identities. This is more about how rasters are dealt with in terms of calculation and memory. A raster is effectively a matrix with values filling the individual cells.

Comment: that is exaxtly my issue, that I need all the information not a single value for a cell. Anyways many thanks for your patience and help. I solved it with cellFromXY() from the raster package!

Comment: So if that is the case, you can just round the X and Y of your points. No need to even invoke a raster.